# Desktop App Converter (UWP creation) -AppId parameter format

Tags: uwp, universal, dac, desktop-app-converter

Desktop App Converter (UWP creation) -AppId parameter correct format. Dev assign number 12345name.name

Wrong (error): -AppId "12345name.name"

Working (but invalid in dev centre): -AppId "name.name12345"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP (Universal Windows Platform) format of -AppId parameter issues using DAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843508/uwp-universal-windows-platform-format-of-appid-parameter-issues-using-dac)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your previous question?

Comment: Not a duplicate question bcse may b the previous question not getting any answer. and you can delete that previous question. Answer is the aim.